# print " ".join(tsOutput) ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am getting error in

> print "".join(tsOutput)

is it due to syntax are different in python 2.x and 3.x versions?

Comment: Which version of python, 2.7 or 3-x?

Comment: If this is python 3, the error is that `print` is a function and needs parentheses. I don't off the top of my head see how this would be a syntax error in python 2.

Comment: You have tags for python-2.7 and python-3.x. Since the syntax for `print` is different in each version, you can't use this line in both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb and say you must be using python 3. In that case, this must be written as `print("".join(tsOutput))`

This is because `print` is a function in python 3, and needs standard function syntax. (In python 2 it was built more tightly into the core language and was an exception to the regular syntax in that it required no parentheses)

Answer (score 2):

You should add parenthesis to your print statement

`print("".join(tsOutput))` should work

Answer (score 0):

`print("".join(tsOutput))` try this.

go through this [site](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) to learn more about python